# Terminal issues with node.js and NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I am new to programming etc, I recently had to submit final project for CS50x and was having issues so had to use sudo to submit project.

I have been trying for the last few hours to fix this, I am now at the point where I completely deleted nodeJS and NPM from my computer, I tried updating prior to deleting and still running into this problem. Any guidance would GREATLY be appreciated.

Ever since then I am getting this message when I open the terminal:

````
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at module.exports (/Users/ashtonlittle/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:42:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ashtonlittle/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v12.22.12 --silent` to unset it.```
````